# How is memory allocated to struct in C++? Is it dynamic or static memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I am quite new to C++ programming. So I just wanted to know if the memory allocation to structs is static or dynamic? This is the code that I basically have.

```
struct student {
    double average;
    struct subjects sub[course_numbers];
};

struct subjects {
    char name;
   int crn;
   int credits;
};
```

Comment: Yes, it's probably one of those two.

Comment: Is there any problem in the question? Because I am seeing a lot of people are just down-voting it. @MatsPetersson which one is it?

Comment: @Jazlyn It solely depends on you. You can allocate struct on stack(e.g. static variable) or allocate it on heap (e.g. using new)

Comment: It could be either. In your example it depends on how you *use* the struct, not on the struct itself.

Comment: You could also have the struct allocated in automatic memory (gobal or file global) or in constant memory (read only segment).  All depends on how and where you declare your instance.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is simply a definition of the data objects "student" and "subject". It's just code and exists neither on the stack nor heap until you put it to work and make an actual type out of it. Here is a code example of doing something with it:

```
//define the struct
struct myStruct
{
    int myInt;
};

// use it
int main(void)
{
    myStruct oStruct{456}; //put on stack, automatically cleaned up at end of main function.
    myStruct* pStruct = new myStruct{654}; //put on heap, must be cleaned up manually.

    delete pStruct; //because you put on heap, clean it up afterwards.
    pStruct = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a code in C and I supposed to convert it into C++ along with all the dynamic allocations to the static allocations.                                        
struct myStruct* ints;                                                                                                 ints = (struct myStruct *) malloc (sizeof(struct myStruct) * numbe_Ints) ;                                                                                                    I have this code in the main and all the structs are defined in a header file and their implementation in cpp file.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense what you did. I got most of it. But then how can i give a size to the struct without using the new operator.

Comment: In C, the sizeof() is needed to reserve space in heap memory. In C++, "new" does this automatically. On the other hand, if you instantiate without new or malloc and instead put it on the stack, the compiler will make sure that the program (when it runs) reserves the required amount of memory for the struct's size. Bottom line: you don't have to specify size.

Answer (score 0):

There are more memory areas than *stack* or *heap*, there is also auto storage and constant storage.  The memory that your instance resides in depends on how and where you define your instance.

Declaring an instance outside of a function places the instance in auto storage.  This is where global and file global variables are declared:

```
My_Struct instance;
// or:
static My_Struct instance;
```

Declaring the variable as non-static inside a function, may place the instance on the *stack* (provided the implementation uses one):

```
void Any_Function()
{
  My_Struct instance;
}
```

Again, the compiler is allowed to represent the structure using references or other means (processor cache), so your instance may not be in the *stack*.

Allocating using `new` places the instance into dynamic memory (a.k.a. heap):

```
void Another_Function()
{
  My_Struct * p_instance = new My_Struct;
  // ...
  delete p_instance;
}
```

You can also place the instance into *constant* memory, or memory where all the constant literals are placed:

```
const My_Struct instance = {/*...*/};
```

You can also place the instance into "global" memory by declaring the instance as `static` inside a function:

```
void Yet_Another_Function()
{
  static My_Struct instance;
}
```

So, to answer your question:  structs are placed into memory depending on how and where the instances are declared.  There are more memory areas than `static` or `dynamic`.  There are multiple definitions of `static`, so you'll have to clarify.  Usually, `dynamic` means during run-time.  A *static* instance may refer to an instance allocated during the compilation / build process.

Comment: In my case, I have a dynamic struct. Thank you for your help :)